# How to add JPA properties to @Bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How could I configure JPA the same as described in 84.5:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties ?

I would like to set spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false but inside a @Bean instead of application.properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check 'Using Java Configuration' in [Bootstrapping Hibernate 5 with Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring)

Alternatively, you can activate some properties using a spring profile